# Optimal combination of “baskets” to best approximate target basket?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Say I have some array of length n where arr[k] represents how much of object k I want. I also have some arbitrary number of arrays which I can sum integer multiples of in any combination - my goal being to minimise the sum of the absolute differences across each element.

So as a dumb example if my target was [2,1] and my options were A = [2,3] and B = [0,1], then I could take A - 2B and have a cost of 0

I’m wondering if there is an efficient algorithm for approximating something like this? It has a weird knapsack-y flavour to is it maybe just intractable for large n? It doesn’t seem very amenable to DP methods

Answer (score 0):

This is the (NP-hard) [closest vector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Closest_vector_problem_(CVP)). There's an algorithm due to Fincke and Pohst (["Improved methods for calculating vectors of short length in a lattice, including a complexity analysis"](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1985-0777278-8)), but I haven't personally worked with it.